# Unable to send Authentication Template Message using whatsapp cloud apis - "Receiver is incapable" Error

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, whatsapp, whatsapp-cloud-api

I am trying to send a message using an authentication template(https://graph.facebook.com/v18.0/xxxxxxxx/messages). However, I am encountering the error "Receiver is incapable of receiving this message."

- The AUthentication template is approved
- This issue only occurs with authentication templates, not with utility templates.
- It works when the user initiates a message.
- I can receive messages from other businesses(same auth message), so does not look like an receiver end issue.

**Sample Payload**

```
"messaging_product": "whatsapp",
    "recipient_type": "individual",
    "to": "91xxxxxxxxx",
    "type": "template",
    "template": {
        "name": "login_otp_v1",
        "language": {
            "code": "en_US"
        },
        
        "components": [
            {
                "type": "body",
                "parameters": [
                    {
                        "type": "text",
                        "text": "567895"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "type": "button",
                "sub_type": "url",
                "index": 0,
                "parameters": [
                    {
                        "type": "text",
                        "text": "567895"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Error Response:

```
{
                    "code": 131026,
                    "title": "Receiver is incapable of receiving this message",
                    "message": "Receiver is incapable of receiving this message",
                    "error_data": {
                      "details": "Message Undeliverable."
                    },
                    "href": "https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/cloud-api/support/error-codes/"
                  }
```

Comment: Have you checked the possible reasons for this error code, on the website mentioned?

Comment: yes, Checked. it states issues with recipient number, but the same WhatsApp number gets OTP from other businesses. The error message seems irrelevant.